# Xcode 8 export archive for client

Tags: swift, xcode

I developed an iOS (the swift based) application for my client. I have enrolled Apple developer program and my client have different one too. My client want from me the Xcode archive, which he can publish on AppStore (he need to re sign with his certificates). He send me his provisioning profile, but I'm unable to generate the Xcode archive. It fails with:
No signing certificate "iOS Distribution" found:  No "iOS Distribution" signing certificate matching team ID "XXXXXXX" with a private key was found.

I also tried to disable code signing in iOS SKD but this is not helping.

How can i solve this problem?

Comment: You need to add both certificates and provisioning profile in your system, which generated by your client

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your client needs to send you his iOS Distribution Certificate (exported from Keychain with his private key) and then you can archive from your xcode.

If he don't know how to do that, he can simply give you access to his Apple developer account (a limited developer access is enough) and then you can generate the iOS Distribution certificate by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I solve this problem as is written above. Client made me part of his team. So I can set provisioning and signing certificate from his team. Now I was able to generate Xcode archive and send him to my client.